# Is there a way to use MSAL completely offline on-premises in .NET Core app to get access and id tokens (without the need for Azure registered App)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, azure-ad-msal

**Intro:**
Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) provides an identity server and management services to issue, cache and validate access and id tokens for a range of types of applications using OAuth2.0 and OpenIdConnect protocol.

**The problem:**
Our requirement is to use OAuth2.0 and OpenIdConnect protocols and an open-source identity server platform to issue and handle access and id tokens "offline" because the system (.NET Core webapp with angular) is often deployed on-premises in internal networks and doesn't have access to the internet. I tried to use MSAL but it always gets to the point where in production it needs the client & tenant id of AzureAD registered app.

**Anyone knows a way to get around that? Or knows another library that meets the requirements?**

**Side notes:**
[Duende Identity Server4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is unfortunately not an option for us due to a collision with their new policy that will apply dec22.
Okta and similar are paid and are out of the scope.

Comment: Where do you want your users to authenticate? Your own server backed by SQL or Active Directory? Or online services like Azure AD?

Comment: Hi CodeCaster! They will be authenticated by our own server backed by SQL in the internal network with no access to the internet.

Comment: Hello @YazanGhafir. Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I'm having a very similar problem with a React application using MSAL with a .NET core backend that will sometimes be deployed on-prem. Any pointers would be much appreciated